# i cant control userReducer actions in context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

i try to use **useReducer**. First of all i try to pass dispatch as a props for getting global state for parent component states. so it's became so confusing and uncontrollable. So i have an idea. what if i create a context inside useReducer and get dispatch event without passing as a props. bu when i do that it returns always initial state and not dispatching any actions.

```
const AuthContext = createContext({
 state: {},
 dispatch:() => {}
});

export const AuthReducerProvider = ({ children }) => {
 const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer);
 const contextValue = useMemo(() => ({ state, dispatch }), [state, dispatch]);

 return <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export const useAuthReducerContext = () => {
 const context = useContext(AuthContext);
 if (context === undefined) {
   throw new Error(`error`);
 }
 return context;
};
```

i wrap my component with AuthReducerProvider. but when i try to import useAuthReducerContext and run dispatch function it's always return as initialValues.

actually my questions is

1- is it an good idea? :D
2- or did a do something wrong

Comment: Maybe memo is what causes the problem.

Comment: Can you show how you're using the AuthReducerProvider component.

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is pretty standard, there's nothing wrong with it. Probably, something else is causing your issue.